# How to browse solidity language source code?

Tags: solidity, evm

Is there an IDE which allows to go to a source code of a selected method (I mean like in case of IntelliJ when you ctrl+click on the method name inside your class and you are redirected to the source code of this method)?
If there is no such IDE / IDE + plugin then how can I easily find a source code of a given method in solidity language?
I tried to do that by cloning solidity [repo](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity) and then searching for method name (tried with array push method), but there was huge amount of results and I am not sure where to search exactly.
Is it even possible to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Also in other languages you can't mostly see the implementation of the language native opcodes. Think of it like searching for the source code of plus operation. If you'll import other contracts or libraries written in solidity you will be able to watch the source code.

You also must understand that solidity compiles to bytecode, this bytecode has the true opcodes your smart contract built of.

Comment: I assumed that there is some readable core API for solidity language where I can find implementation of common operations. But I suppose it was wrong assumption. For example when compared to Java we can say that both solidity and Java have their VM and bytecodes but in case of Java you can also find it's core API implementation. See for example OpenJDK - https://github.com/openjdk/jdk. But I understand that it's not the case in case of Solidity.